# How to pass date from shell script to java Instant data type

Tags: java, shell

I passed the following

`NOW=$(date +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S)`

`timestamp:"'$NOW'"` in curl body,

but the deserialization failed.

What format does Java Instant accept?

Comment: Can you please add the type and the annotations if there is any, of your `timestamp` property

Comment: Consider running curl -v, and sharing the log and output. Good idea will be to share the relevant part of the script that perform the POST

Answer (score 1):

try the below :

```
NOW=$(date --utc +%FT%TZ)
```